# Stack Overflow says bounty ended, but it didn't yet

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty, notifications

I got a notification that my bounty ended:

[image]

And also an email:

[image]

However, the bounty is still active:

[image]

Why is Stack Overflow trying to mislead me to award the bounty before it ends?

Comment: See [Bug in time of expiring bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235330/bug-in-time-of-expiring-bounty)

Comment: @animuson I'd rather have the notice just _always_ happen after ending than confusingly sometimes before.

Comment: Loads of free hand circles! Wow, you just made my day better. Thanks.